# Will the collect of the Flow block to execute?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I run the Code A and get the Result A. In my mind, it should be the Result B.

It seems that `flow.collect { value -> println(value) }` block to execute.

Will the collect of the Flow block to execute ?

**Code A**

```
fun simple(): Flow<Int> = flow { 
    println("Flow started")
    for (i in 1..3) {
        delay(300)
        emit(i)
    }
}

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    println("Calling simple function...")
    val flow = simple()
    println("Calling collect...")
    flow.collect { value -> println(value) } //Block?
    println("Calling collect again...")   
}
```

**Result A**

```
Calling simple function...
Calling collect...
Flow started
1
2
3
Calling collect again...
```

**Result B**

```
Calling simple function...
Calling collect...
Flow started
Calling collect again...
1
2
3
```

BTW, I run Code 1 and get the result 1 as I expected.

**Code 1**

```
fun simple(): Flow<Int> = flow {
    for (i in 1..3) {
        delay(100) 
        emit(i) 
    }
}

fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {  
    launch {
        for (k in 1..3) {
            println("I'm not blocked $k")
            delay(100)
        }
    }  
    simple().collect { value -> println(value) } 
}
```

**Result 1**

```
I'm not blocked 1
1
I'm not blocked 2
2
I'm not blocked 3
3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suspend functions do not block, but they *are* synchronous, meaning the execution of the code in the coroutine waits for the suspend function to return before continuing. The difference between suspend function calls and blocking function calls is that the thread is released to be used for other tasks while the coroutine is waiting for the suspend function to return.

`collect` is a suspend function that internally calls its lambda repeatedly and synchronously (suspending, not blocking) and doesn't return until the Flow is completed.

`launch` is an asynchronous function that starts a coroutine. It returns immediately without waiting for its coroutine to complete, which is why Code 1 behaved as you expected.

Comment: but collect is called from "runBlocking". Docs say that this method runs a new coroutine and blocks the current thread until its completion. So any suspending function should block the thread. And since "launch" starts coroutine in the same "main" thread, shouldn't be there a deadlock?

Comment: @Ov3r1oad `launch` only starts coroutines in the same thread it is called from if it is launched from a CoroutineScope that has a CoroutineContext that specifies a single-threaded dispatcher that happens to use the same thread that called `launch`. None of that is true in this case. `runBlocking` has its own special CoroutineScope, and there's no way it could be using a dispatcher that uses the same thread that is running the `main()` function, because the main function here has no event loop. Only threads with event loops can be used by dispatchers.

Comment: @Ov3r1oad You might be thinking of Android, where `lifecycleScope` and `viewModelScope` both return CoroutineScopes that *do* have a CoroutineContext that uses `Dispatchers.Main`. It is possible to create a deadlock on Android by using `runBlocking` from the main thread and then launching a coroutine from one of these scopes inside it.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about Android, sorry for not mentioning that. And it's the android where I tried this exact example. And there was no deadlock. And I still don't understand why. We have one coroutine started by `runBlocking`. It should block a main thread with any function like `delay`. Also, we have second coroutine started with `launch` in the same main thread (I checked it). And this second coroutine works fine during the `delay`s for 5 seconds in the first coroutine. Why?

Comment: @Ov3r1oad Suspend functions *never* block if designed correctly. They must always delegate anything that would be blocking to another thread/dispatcher while they suspend and wait for it. So `delay()` will never block the thread it is called from, under any circumstances. `runBlocking` does not have some mechanism for breaking suspend functions and forcing them to block. `runBlocking` runs its coroutine normally in a thread separate from the thread you called it from. Conceptually, it's like using a scope to `launch` a coroutine and then sleeping the thread until that coroutine finishes.

Comment: To create a deadlock in Android, if I recall correctly, use `runBlocking`, and inside its coroutine lambda, use `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)`. The reason this would deadlock is that `runBlocking` is blocking the main thread it was called from while it runs its coroutine normally, doing things on background threads. But when it reaches a `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` block, it delegates to the Main dispatcher to run that block of code, and the Main dispatcher submits it to the Main Looper. But since Main is being blocked by `runBlocking`, the Looper can never process it.

Comment: hm. If I put `runBlocking` inside `onCreate` method in android app with the `delay(10000)` and then `launch` after that delay, then the main thread will be blocked for 10 seconds. I mean, only after the 10 seconds the "launch coroutine" starts. I think I am totally lost.

Comment: Yes, `runBlocking` is doing the blocking, not `delay()`. `runBlocking` causes the thread it was called from to block, while the suspend functions called inside its coroutine are not blocking any threads directly. If you're familiar with Java threads, imagine this code called from the main thread: `val myThread = object Thread() { override fun run() { Thread.sleep(10000) } }; myThread.start(); myThread.join()` In this example, the `sleep` call didn't block the main thread--it blocked `myThread`. The main thread was blocked by waiting for `myThread` to finish its background work.